# Wordpress Settings API not saving options

Tags: theme-development

I just started learning the Wordpress Settings API and things are not as easy as I first tought.I have created a section and two fields and it seems that the fields are not saving the data.Each time I click on the field the data gets deleted.Here is my code:

```
<?php
    function thanathos_theme_menu(){
        add_menu_page(
                        'Thanathos',
                        'Thanathos',
                        'administrator',
                        'thanathos_menu_id',
                        'thanathos_menu_display_callback'
                     );
        add_submenu_page(
                        'thanathos_menu_id',
                        'Blog Page',
                        'Blog Page',
                        'administrator',
                        'thanathos_social_logo_options',
                        'thanathos_menu_display_callback'
                     );
    }
    add_action('admin_menu' , 'thanathos_theme_menu');

    function thanathos_menu_display_callback(){
?>      <div class="wrap">
            <div id="icon-themes" class="icon32"></div>
            <h2>Thanathos Theme Options</h2>
            <?php settings_errors(); ?>
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
                 <?php settings_fields( 'thanathos_social_logo_options' ); ?> 
                 <?php do_settings_sections( 'thanathos_social_logo_options' ); ?>
                <?php  submit_button(); ?>
            </form>  
        </div>
<?php }?>
<?php
    function thanathos_initialize_social_logo_options(){
        if(false == get_option('thanathos_social_logo_options')){
            add_option('thanathos_social_logo_options');
        }       
        add_settings_section(
                    'logo_social_section',
                    'Logo & Social Options',
                    'logo_social_section_callback',
                    'thanathos_social_logo_options'
                );
        add_settings_field(
                    'logo_field',
                    'Logo URL',
                    'logo_field_callback',
                    'thanathos_social_logo_options',
                    'logo_social_section'
                );
        add_settings_field(
                    'facebook_field',
                    'Facebook URL',
                    'facebook_field_callback',
                    'thanathos_social_logo_options',
                    'logo_social_section'
                );
        register_setting(
                    'thanathos_social_logo_options',
                    'thanathos_social_logo_options'
                );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'thanathos_initialize_social_logo_options' );
    function logo_social_section_callback(){}

    function logo_field_callback(){
        $option = get_option('thanathos_social_logo_options'); 
        echo '<input type="text" id="logo" name="thanathos_social_logo_options[logo_field]" value="' . $options['logo_field'] . '" />';
    }
     function facebook_field_callback(){
        $option = get_option('thanathos_social_logo_options'); 
        echo '<input type="text" id="facebook" name="thanathos_social_logo_options[facebook_field]" value="' . $options['facebook_field'] . '" />';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well , actually the error is pretty minor , on your callbacks you have wrote

```
function logo_field_callback(){
        $option = get_option('thanathos_social_logo_options'); 
        echo '<input type="text" id="logo" name="thanathos_social_logo_options[logo_field]" value="' . $options['logo_field'] . '" />';
    }
     function facebook_field_callback(){
        $option = get_option('thanathos_social_logo_options'); 
        echo '<input type="text" id="facebook" name="thanathos_social_logo_options[facebook_field]" value="' . $options['facebook_field'] . '" />';
    }
```

as you can see, you load as $option but print as $options, that is your only issue